# Swift WebView not loading some redirections

Tags: swift

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url,
            let scheme = url.scheme else {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                return
            }

            //UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]  <- works but i dont want to open it in safari
            //webView.load(URLRequest(url: url)) <- dont works
            decisionHandler(.allow) <- dont works
}
```

Not loading this website whit neither the load or decisionHandler method: (it loads the rest of the links, but not this ad)

https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsulcITSmZ0z5pq-Fm4gRcby0MY3XDGdBQ9P0VcUSq5vRrRY5oquSebdiCSkVQsI3C-5KypcWh_RVVN9I62STn_vbYr6hA6UcYTpZEfw0Hm1swqBGpmD3ZJDq1QCoC_XOkNMLGXHJwm4Jk9Zjw0l9K-HsGUbzZmGRusq1qZ-yJEXVMWtDF7oBM3uayRqQ4QCsJPJHCgzl9dULq-cAQvnYG4mlM3_Lo-EenB1UXciUMthZX-qzjD0ioVHbezNjN94Ona5UdkmOg4v3ipF3RVFXO7YyPjsblSkUOI5K5VgtHi3KObSDZDtg3g2x0AAASgU8Q&sai=AMfl-YSar3L61Tu_2cYOdew53xYAKFUkSe0nXaSrK_cbcVfon6D6hUTQ7tQmArm_V2o3VspTdDNjXQ7aSCVdw1XsGfAzrbheRzyS2lgFDbfsTrTR&sig=Cg0ArKJSzBZk-HtVwUYF&fbs_aeid=%5Bgw_fbsaeid%5D&adurl=https://www.iberdrola.es/servicios/equipos/smart-solar/oferta-energia-solar-unifamiliar-comunidades&nm=1&nx=225&ny=-37&mb=1&clkt=2

And this one not even calling the func `decidePolicyFor navigationAction:`

https://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=300&winname=addthis&pub=ra-62320da012f4f327&source=tbx-300&lng=es&s=whatsapp&wid=i1gy&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tribunavalladolid.com%2F&title=Tribuna%20de%20Valladolid.%20Noticias%20Castilla%20y%20Le%C3%B3n.%20Noticias%20Valladolid&ate=AT-ra-62320da012f4f327/-/-/62ff3759d4f4d6bb/8&frommenu=1&ips=1&uid=62cfeb788b64c651&description=Noticias%20sobre%20Valladolid%20y%20su%20provincia.%20Deportes%2C%20sucesos%2C%20cultura%2C%20econom%C3%ADa%2C%20empresas%2C%20en%20tu%20peri%C3%B3dico%20digital%20de%20Valladolid.&uud=1&ct=1&pre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&tt=0&captcha_provider=recaptcha2&pro=0

Comment: What is the URL that you are trying to load? Is it http or https?

Comment: the url of the post. Its https @Fogmeister